# For cycle or for each with js objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem to add a onclick event to object who can be many times in same page

I am trying to

```
   var i;
   for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    var tmpObj='lov_DgId_D_'+i;
    var tmpObj2=tmpObj.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if (tmpObj2 != null) {
            tmpObj2.onclick= DgIdOnClick;
        }
    }
```

But got a error TypeError:

```
Object lov_DgId_D_1 has no method 'getElementsByTagName' , but this is working 
lov_DgId_D_2.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick= DgIdOnClick;
```

This `ibject lov_DgId_D_` can be from 1  `like lov_DgId_D_1 or lov_DgId_D_99` u.t.c

What wil be the best solution to add onclick to all lov_DgId_D_* objects ?

Comment: Is tmpObj the id of an element ? Or what ?

Comment: It's a string : `var tmpObj='lov_DgId_D_'+i;`.

Comment: OK in script it is a string but later i am using tmpObj to get getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; and got the error Object lov_DgId_D_1 has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: A string doesn't have that function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is a confusion between the id of an element and the actual element. Some code that should work for you is this one:

```
   var i;
   for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    var tmpObj=document.getElementById('lov_DgId_D_'+i); // <-- here
    var tmpObj2=tmpObj.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if (tmpObj2 != null) {
            tmpObj2.onclick= DgIdOnClick;
        }
    }
```

Slightly easier to read code:

```
for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  var anchor = document.querySelector('#lov_DgId_D_'+i + ' a');
  if (anchor) anchor.onclick = DgIdOnClick;
}
```

A note: this code attaches a click event to the first anchor (`a` element) inside each element with the id lov_DgId_D_n, with n being 1->10. Your original code seems to want to do the same thing.

Another note: usually when you iterate over elements using their id's to identify them, you are better suited to add a class to those elements instead. It provides for more maintaintable code and probably easier to understand as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you use jquery, the simplest is

```
for (i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
    $('#lov_DgId_D_'+ i+ ' a').click(DgIdOnClick);
}
```

If you want to bind your event handler to all `a` elements inside elements whose id starts with `lov_DgId_D_`, then it's as simple as

```
$('[id^="lov_DgId_D_"] a').click(DgIdOnClick);
```

Comment: The idea is right but bought variants are not working corectly like onclick with click event. With CLick event Lov is opening first only then a call function